# Bug Issues - SQL Query needs to edit one row

Tags: sql-server

Ive got a bug which ive been looking into with my SQL code, when i try and update a user it decides to edit my whole database rather then one entry. The code worked previous until i put it into a single entry rather than individual ones.

```
IF exists (SELECT USERID FROM WUSERS WHERE USERID='XXXXX')
begin

-- Update it
print 'updated'
update WUSERS set FULLNAME= 'XXXXX' update WUSERS set PW= 'XXXXX' update WUSERS set telno= 'XXXXX' update WUSERS set email= 'XXXXX@email.com' update WUSERS set ROLEID= 'X' update WUSERS set dept= 'XXX' where userid= 'XXXXX'
end

else
begin

-- add it
print 'added'
insert into WUSERS (USERID,PW,FULLNAME,TELNO,EMAIL,ROLEID,DEPT) Values ('XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX@email.com','X','XXX')
end
```

This is what ive currently got and im struggling to see whats gone wrong. Please ignore the X's this is just in placement of actual data.

Cheers,

Owen

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: there is no where clause on your update statement

Comment: you need a where clause for each one

Comment: Now that you have an answer to the problem I have to point out that you have what appears to be some challenges with your design. First is it looks like you may be storing password in plain text. This is an absolute no win. They must be salted and hashed. Next is you have RoleID. This limits a user to a single role which is very likely not the case in most systems. You have the same challenge with department. Sometimes people work for multiple departments and your structure won't support that.

Comment: @SeanLange we have a max of nine roles in this database as a lot of the rolls are set to 0 or null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate statements with a semicolon.  However, you just want to set multiple columns:

```
update WUSERS
    set FULLNAME = 'XXXXX',
        PW = 'XXXXX',
        telno = 'XXXXX',
        email = 'XXXXX@email.com',
        ROLEID = 'X',
        dept = 'XXX'
    where userid= 'XXXXX';
```

Comment: Just a style note: IMHO `SET` should be on the same line as `UPDATE` since it is required for the `UPDATE` syntax, and the column assignments would then be indented only one level. Less lines, less indented. `UPDATE ... SET` is like `SELECT ...` in that it introduces a list of required non table-like items. `SET` is different to `FROM`, which introduces a list (usually size 1) of tables.

Comment: @Bohemian . . . There are many styles for SQL.  I am biased to putting keywords that start clauses at the beginning of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Each update statement needs a where clause, not just the last one...

eg.

```
update WUSERS set FULLNAME= 'XXXXX' 
update WUSERS set PW= 'XXXXX'
```

Should be;

```
update WUSERS set FULLNAME= 'XXXXX' WHERE Whatever
update WUSERS set PW= 'XXXXX' WHERE Whatever
```

As a side note, you can update multiple fields in one go like;

```
update WUSERS set FULLNAME= 'XXXXX',
                  PW= 'XXXXX' 
WHERE Whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple update which operated each other on all lines, you can rewrite it to one update wich have a `WHERE` clause

Replace your 6 update statment wich look like

```
UPDATE WUSERS
   SET FULLNAME = 'XXXXX'

UPDATE WUSERS
   SET PW = 'XXXXX'

UPDATE WUSERS
   SET telno = 'XXXXX'

UPDATE WUSERS
   SET email = 'XXXXX@email.com'

UPDATE WUSERS
   SET ROLEID = 'X'

UPDATE WUSERS
   SET dept = 'XXX'
 WHERE userid = 'XXXXX'
```

By

```
UPDATE WUSERS
   SET FULLNAME = 'XXXXX',
       PW = 'XXXXX',
       telno = 'XXXXX',
       email = 'XXXXX@email.com',
       ROLEID = 'X',
       dept = 'XXX'
 WHERE userid = 'XXXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

For each update statement that you have, you must specify a `where` clause. Think about it, you're telling the database to update the table `WUSERS` to set `FULLNAME = 'xxxx'`. How does the database know which exact row to update when you haven't told it?

E.g.

```
update WUSERS set FULLNAME= 'XXXXX' where "some_logical_statement"
```

Alternatively, you can also include a single where clause at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your using multiple updates and the where statement is only getting found on the last update statement, put the updates together like the following:

```
IF exists (SELECT USERID FROM WUSERS WHERE USERID='XXXXX')
begin

-- Update it
print 'updated'
UPDATE WUSERS 
SET FULLNAME = 'XXXXX',
    PW = 'XXXXX',
    telno = 'XXXXX',
    email = 'XXXXX@email.com',
    ROLEID = 'X',
    dept = 'XXX' 
where userid= 'XXXXX'

END

ELSE
BEGIN

    -- add it
    print 'added'
    insert into WUSERS (USERID,PW,FULLNAME,TELNO,EMAIL,ROLEID,DEPT) 
    Values ('XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX','XXXXX@email.com','X','XXX')

END
```